# Cannot see my AppWidget, that I'm trying to add to existing application

Tags: android, xml, android-appwidget

I'm studying how to write own android applications. I wrote one by myself, and now I'm trying to implement an AppWidget for it.

I'm using [this page](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) as a guideline for my work.

I decided to implement an AppWidget, that will not have any logic at first, just a layout.
The project builds and run without errors, but, when I'm trying to add my widget to launcher, I don't see it in the list of available widgets.

I only can see my application in the list of applications, that have widgets, but, when trying to filter widgets by application, I see nothing.

I've searched for a solution, but didn't find any. Just found a problem with appwidgets in android 4.0.4, that is solved by rebooting a device or stating the main application if the widget has any.

The code of my widget you can see lower.

What is wrong in it? Is the problem in empty class?

---

I made the following changes in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="ru.pinedevelop.wind.NormalWidget"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
   android:resource="@xml/normal_widget" />
</receiver>
```

Then added the following desctiption to xml/normal_widget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:minWidth="146dip"
                android:minHeight="72dip"
                android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
                android:resizeMode="none"
                android:initialLayout="@layout/normal_widget_main" />
```

Later I added the following layout for my widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:background="@drawable/appwidget_dark_bg">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_spot_name"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
              android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_spot_update_time"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
              android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_max_label"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:text="@string/widget_label_max"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                      android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_max_value"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                      android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_avg_label"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:text="@string/widget_label_avg"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                      android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_avg_value"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                      android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_min_label"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:text="@string/widget_label_min"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                      android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_min_value"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                      android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/widget_arrow"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow50"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:contentDescription="@string/widget_arrow_descr"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And created a dummy class for it:

```
package ru.pinedevelop.wind;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
public class NormalWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that a problem was in widget declaration.

I just edited a line, adding "http://":

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"...
```